# Adjacency List implementation in c++`using Linked List

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, adjacency-list

I have seen many implementations of the adjacency list. Here, I try to implement it using c++. As you can tell from my c++ structure, I am a total newbie in c++. Here i am struggling trying to get my code running. My current problem is, it does not go through the whole graph. and I get a segmentation fault. 
Result:

vertex: 0

1->

vertex: 1

2->3->

vertex: 2

vertex: 3

vertex: 4

Segmentation fault

I need some help getting this to run. I want to implement DFS algorithm. Any tips would be great!!!

Here is Header:

```
#ifndef DFS_H
#define DFS_H

class DFS{
private:
    struct vertex{
        int data;
        bool visited;
        struct vertex* next;
    };  
    int V;
    struct vertex* G[20];
public:
    DFS(int vertices);
    vertex* addVertex(int data);
    void addEdge(int index, int data);
    void dfs(int vertex);
    void printGraph();
};

#endif
```

cpp file:

```
#include "DFS.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
DFS:: DFS(int vertices){
    this->V=vertices;
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
        G[i]= NULL; 
    }
}
DFS::vertex* DFS::addVertex(int data){
    struct vertex* newNode= new vertex;
    newNode->data= data;
    newNode->next= NULL;
    newNode->visited=false;
    return newNode;
}
void DFS:: addEdge(int index, int data){
    struct vertex* cursor;
    struct vertex* newVertex= addVertex(data);

    if(G[index]==NULL)
        G[index]=newVertex;
    else{
        cursor=G[index];
        while(cursor->next!=NULL)
            cursor=cursor->next;
        cursor->next= newVertex; 
    }
}
void DFS::printGraph(){
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
        struct vertex* cursor= G[i];
        cout<<"vertex: "<<i<<endl;
        while(cursor->next!=NULL){
            cout<<cursor->data<<"->";
            cursor=cursor->next;    
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void DFS:: dfs(int vertex){
}
int main(){
    DFS dfs(5);
    dfs.addEdge(0,1);
    dfs.addEdge(0,4);
    dfs.addEdge(1,2);
    dfs.addEdge(1,3);
    dfs.addEdge(1,4);
    dfs.addEdge(2,3);
    dfs.addEdge(3,4);

    dfs.printGraph();
    return 0;   
}
```

*

Thanks for your help Stackoverflow community!

Comment: You need to revist how arrays work.  `struct vertex* G[];` is not valid.

Comment: Yes... I see that. That is why I am asking here. I am trying to make an array of vertex. So how would you go about that?

Comment: Do you know how many you need?  If not instead of using an array you should consider a `std::vector`.

Comment: No, It is up to the user to indicate how many Vertices they want to insert. The amount of vertices they want to pass is passed in the constructor. where 'V' is the amount of vertices. an example of this is found here, http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-adjacency-list/

Comment: **Learn one new thing at a time.** If you want to learn arrays, play around with `int`, `int*` and `int[]`. Until you master that, don't attempt `vertex[]`. And until you master *that*, don't attempt DFS.

Comment: Okay sorry yall are pissed off that I used an array incorrectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoseOrtiz -- You basically took some code that either is an attempt by a `C` programmer trying to write `C++` (the `struct` keyword used in various places is a dead giveaway this may be the case), or you got the code from a very old (or very poor) C++ book or sample.   Your vertex class looks like a `std::forward_list`, thus all you need is [std::forward_list<vertex>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) and get rid of the `next` member variable in vertex, as it is not necessary if forward_list is used.

Comment: hahaha! nice! Well I looked at alot of code both in C and C++ and tried creating my own from scratch. I I don't really want to use anything like forward_list. I want to create everything from scratch

Comment: So is your goal to create a graph object, or to maintain a linked list?  If it's the latter, write a linked list class.  If it's the former, then use a linked list class already written to get you started in completing the goal of creating a graph object.  Also, and I'm going to say this -- I have yet to see a beginner write a linked list class properly, without error, without side-effects from occurring, etc.  Almost every day on SO is the "linked list question", about how to properly implement it.  If you want to go down that path, well I wish you luck.

Comment: And now your graph object is full of memory leaks, doesn't adhere to the "rule of 3", etc.  Just use `std::vector` to implement a dynamic array and most, if not all of these issues go away.

Comment: I want to create a graph. An adjacency List. That is why i create an array of vertex struct in the constructor. with vertices, being the amount of vertices needed for the graph

Comment: @JoseOrtiz -- Here is your code (or what I believe is equivalent to your code) using the [standard containers](http://ideone.com/G6qAGX).  You see that not a single pointer is used, and no memory leaks.

Comment: If you had to implement the adjacency list the way I am doing it here, with linked list, how would you do it. without using vector or anything

Comment: @JoseOrtiz *how would you do it. without using vector or anything* -- Remember that myself and others helping you are not beginners or novices at C++.  What I and others would do is create our own "vector" and "list" classes and use them if those were the requirements.  We wouldn't be strewing `new[] / delete[]` calls all over the place -- we would have the knowledge to encapsulate them into our own  class and manage the memory in a coherent manner.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. That is what I would like to do. I would like to create my own list and vector class. An example of that is what I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segfault comes from `printGraph` which assumes all `V` vertices are present, which is not true in your case. Notice there is no `dfs.addEdge(4, ...)` initializing the 5th vertex.

In general that approach that the length must match the number of elements set later on is asking for trouble, I'd refactor this code using a `vector` for storage.

Another problem is that `addEdge` always instantiates a new `vertex` which means after `dfs.addEdge(1,3)` and `dfs.addEdge(2,3)` vertices 1 and 2 will point to different instances of vertex 3.

Another thing: `addEdge(1,2)` and `addEdge(1,3)` will leave you with edges *1->2* and *2->3*. I assume the result should be edges *1->2* and *1->3*.

Not to mention that returning a bare `new`ed pointer from `addVertex` is asking for a memory leak; I'd suggest using an `auto_ptr` (`unique_ptr` if you're on C++11).

Another thing is you are reimplementing a forward-linked list when `std::forward_list` is available.

These are just a few problems I spotted just by looking at your code. I'm sure there are more because, to be honest, it looks pretty bad (no offense, we all used to be beginners). I suggest what @Beta said: learning and practicing one thing at a time (build a vertex list, when you're comfortable with that figure out how to represent edges, then try to traverse it, build a simple algorithm, etc).

Comment: Yes a beginner to c++ , I'm coming from Java. haha. Well this is pretty embarrassing. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.